# .NET Reflection on unloadable types

Tags: .net, reflection

I have a library which contains unloadable type (whenever I try to access them I get a TypeLoadException). Therefore, I can't use the System.Reflection namespace to inspect those types. Is there some other way to reflect on those types. Of course, I don't expect to be able to use any methods, I just want to see basic info such as method names and perhaps the argument types.

Edit: I know and accept that the type is unloadable, it is because it defines its own System.Object and it does not have a reference to mscorlib. Reflector and ildasm work, but I want to do the reflection on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [Mono.Cecil](http://mono-project.com/Cecil) to reflect the assembly. Unfortunately you'd have to change your reflection code as the interfaces are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) - it should be able to show you some of the metadata about those types.  If that doesn't work, try using [ILDASM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1(VS.80).aspx) to disassemble the assembly to see the type's metadata.

Comment: Yes, both of those tools can do the inspection for me, but I want to do it in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` to load the assembly.

see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172331.aspx)

Comment: He's getting a TypeLoadException when he does it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't make a difference.